# Why does the dual problem of the SDP become a maximum eigenvalue problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, semidefinite-programming

This SDP problem with the variable $X \in \mbox{S}^n$ where $\rho \gt 0$
$$\max  \mbox{Tr}(AX) - \rho \mbox{1}\lvert X \rvert \mbox{1} \\ 
\mathrm{subject\;  to}\;\mbox{Tr}(X)=1, \\
X \succeq 0 $$

is rewritten  as 
$$\max_{\mbox{Tr}(X)=1, \\
X \succeq 0} \;\; \min_{\lvert U_{ij} \rvert \le \rho} \mbox{Tr}(X(A+U)) \\
$$

Then this yields the following dual
$$ \min \lambda^{max}(A+U)  \\
\mathrm{subject\;  to}\;\lvert U_{ij} \rvert \le \rho\;\;i,j=1,\dots, n $$

Why is this dual problem maximum eigenvalue problem?
My old optimization text says the dual problem obtained from Lagrange Dual function which is the infimum of the Lagrangian. So I think $\rho$ is the Lagrange multiplier but maximum eigenvalue problem seems so different type of problem.

This is from the paper http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/CSD-04-1330.pdf

Comment: Does this help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508303/minimum-eigenvalue-representation/1508492